# Restart the app when i click on the back button

Tags: android, listview, keyboard

I'm creating an app, a listvView wich contains four EdiTexts, and a button for each row, but When I edit the editText and i click on the back button to hide the keyboard, it deletes all the values ! 
It's little troubling, and i can't keep developping it!
If you have any idean i'm taking.
Thanks for your time and have a good day.

edit : 
I want, when i click on the back button, to hide the keyboard without, cleaning all the values, i'll joind the apk if you want/need ^^, thanks for the quick answer.
there is the link to the app :

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwyELfc-0SheZlo3cElfSzdERnc/edit?usp=sharing

Sorry for my bad english and post.

Comment: What is your question, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want, when i click on the back button, to hide the keyboard without, cleaning all the values, i'll joind the apk if you want/need ^^, thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way is to store your values when you press back button. Example for one edittext:

```
String temp1 = "";
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        editText1.setText(temp1);
    }
});



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    temp1 = editText1.getText.toString();
}
```